# Automating exploratory plots using purrr and several different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr

I really love using purrr to automate my exploratory plots, which I learned how to do via this blog post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/automating-exploratory-plots-with-ggplot2-and-purrr/

However, one issue with the code in this blog post is that you have to specify the dataset in the function. I would like to generalize the dataset in the function so that I can change the dataset as I see fit.

I have tried everything I can think of to do this but am really stuck. Any suggestions?

```
###Sample dataset

dataSet <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2),
                      col1 = c(3.5,4.5,6.5,7.6),
                      col2 = c(1.2,2.3,4.5,6.7),
                      col3 = c(9.8,7.6,5.4,5.6),
                      timepoint = c(1,2,1,2))

###Sample function

plot_func <- function(x,y,d) {
  ggplot(d, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]])) +
    geom_line(aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], group = id), size = 1, alpha = 0.3)
}

###Specify variables of interest

exposures <- names(dataSet)[2:4]
timepoint <- names(dataSet)[5]

##Name variables of interest

exposures <- purrr::set_names(exposures)
timepoint <- purrr::set_names(timepoint)

###This doesn't work because need to specify the dataset, but no matter what I try I can't figure out where to put the dataset in the formula

plots = map(exposures,
            ~map(timepoint, plot_func, y = .x) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only loop over `exposures` with one timepoint then the following should do it:

```
plots = map(exposures, ~ plot_func(x = timepoint, y = .x, d = dataSet))
```

You can just use the lamda notation to fill in the variables you want to specify. `.x` is your input to `map` in this case `exposures`.

See the code below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

###Sample dataset

dataSet <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2),
                      col1 = c(3.5,4.5,6.5,7.6),
                      col2 = c(1.2,2.3,4.5,6.7),
                      col3 = c(9.8,7.6,5.4,5.6),
                      timepoint = c(1,2,1,2),
                      timepoint2 = c(3,4,3,4))

### Sample function
plot_func <- function(x,y,d) {
  ggplot(d, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]])) +
    geom_line(aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], group = id), size = 1, alpha = 0.3)
}

### Specify variables of interest
exposures <- names(dataSet)[2:4]
timepoint <- names(dataSet)[5]
timepoint2 <- names(dataSet)[5:6]

##Name variables of interest
exposures <- purrr::set_names(exposures)
timepoint <- purrr::set_names(timepoint)
timepoint2 <- purrr::set_names(timepoint2)

### This works

plots <- map(exposures, ~ plot_func(x = timepoint, y = .x, d = dataSet))

plots
#> $col1
#> $col2
#> $col3
```

If you want to loop over `exposures` and timepoint variables (I added `timepoint2` as another timepoint column), then you can use a nested `map` call:

```r
plots2 <- map(exposures, ~ map(timepoint2, function(z) plot_func(x = z, y = .x, d = dataSet)))

plots2
#> $col1
#> $col1$timepoint
#> $col1$timepoint2
#> $col2
#> $col2$timepoint
#> $col2$timepoint2
#> $col3
#> $col3$timepoint
#> $col3$timepoint2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!!